# Using switch by parameter in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, switch-statement, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to determine, where to upload build artifacts buy using switch, which depends on parameter.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters{

    // Some other params..

    choice(name: 'DeployTo', choices: ['Diawi', 'GoogleDrive', 'None'], description: 'Whenever to upload build to diawi or google drive. Set to None if you do not want to upload build')

    }
    stages {

        // Some other stages..

        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                sh "echo 'Deploy build (${BUILD_NUMBER}) to ${params.DeployTo}'"
                switch(params.DeployTo) {
                    case "Diawi":
                    sh """
                        node ${params.DiawiUploadScriptPath} ${getBuildPath()} ${params.DiawiUploadToken}
                    """
                    break
                    case "GoogleDrive":
                    sh """
                        node ${params.GDriveUploadScriptPath} ${params.ProjectName} ${BUILD_NUMBER} ${getBuildPath()}
                    """
                    break
                    default:
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I get the error

```
WorkflowScript: 43: Expected a step @ line 43, column 5.
                switch(params.DeployTo) {
```

So, how do I select steps using switch statement and a string/choice parameters?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `switch` or any other groovy control flow in a [declarative pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-pipeline). For that you have to use [scripted pipelines](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#scripted-pipeline) instead.

In a declarative pieline, you can at most use the [`when`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) step for simple control flow logic, or wrap a scripted pipeline in a [`script`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#script) step.

Comment: Thank you! I used "script{}" wrapper, but I'll take a look at scripted pipelines.